# A question about infinite utility streams

Tags: order-theory, economics

At the end of Diamond's [Evaluation of Infinite Utility Streams](http://folk.uio.no/gasheim/zDia1965.pdf) he proves a theorem (which he doesn't give a name to, but it's at the very end of the article). There is a step in which he jumps from $(u,0)_{rep}\succ (0,u)_{rep}$ to $(u,0)\succ_t (0,u)$, and I don't understand where that comes from. It seems like it's the opposite direction of axiom A2, and I don't see how that's derived.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step:** $(u,0)_{rep}\succ (0,u)_{rep}\implies (u,0)\succ_2(0,u)$

**Proof:** Suppose not. Since $\succeq_2$ is complete, we would have $(0,u)\succeq_2 (u,0)$ otherwise, and hence by **A2** $(0,u)_{rep}\succeq (u,0)_{rep}$. This cannot be.

I don't see how the rest of Diamond's proof works out though. $(u,0,U)\succeq(0,u,U)$ follows now from **A1**, but I don't see why this should be strict.

Comment: Good point. But adding a strict variant of (A1) doesn't seem remarkably controversial, relative to the other axioms.

Comment: @Xodarap It isn't, but I'm a sucker for minimalism. Thanks for the bounty!